# Sox play stopping playback when called in Java

Tags: java, playback, sox, mute

I need to play streamed audio from Java, primarily online radio stations. I used `play --magic [url]` for this, which seemed to work fine on the terminal. So I used Runtime to start the process from Java.

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"play", "--magic", station}, new String[]{"AUDIODEV=pcm.radsound"});
p.waitFor();
```

This works fine for one or two minutes but after that the sound disappears. The process still continues to run and `p.waitFor();` does not return. I get no exceptions, nothing in `p.getErrorStream()`, no indication of something not working. I have no clue what's going wrong here, specially after I went back and checked that calling the same command from the terminal just keeps on playing indefinitely.

I thought maybe it has something to do with getting the streamed data, so I split the thing in two. Used `curl` to fill a pipe and then `play` to play it. Didn't change a thing.

For clarification: This has to run on a RaspberryPi 4B running Raspbery Pi OS.

Any help and/or pointers very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Just to be certain that the process is not stuck because of a full stdout or stderr buffer, it’s a good idea to use `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("play, "--magic", station).inheritIO(); builder.environment().put("AUDIODEV", "pcm.radsound"); Process p = builder.start();`.  ProcessBuilder is the modern replacement for Runtime.exec.  The important part is the inheritIO call, which makes the child process use the calling program’s input/output/error descriptors.

Comment: @VGR thank you so much!! When using the ProcessBuilder it just works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be certain that the process is not stuck because of a full stdout or stderr buffer, it’s a good idea to use:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("play, "--magic", station);
builder.inheritIO();
builder.environment().put("AUDIODEV", "pcm.radsound");
Process p = builder.start();
```

ProcessBuilder is the modern replacement for Runtime.exec.  The important part is the [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) call, which makes the child process use the calling program’s input/output/error descriptors.